# How can I copy a column from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables. I need to copy data from one table to another based on id

table1

```
+----+------------------------+------+
| id | title                  | year |
+----+------------------------+------+
|  1 | Carmencita             | 1894 |
|  2 | Le clown et ses chiens | 1892 |
|  3 | Pauvre Pierrot         | 1892 |
+----+------------------------+------+
```

table 2:

```
+----+------------------------+------+
| id | title                  | year |
+----+------------------------+------+
|  1 | Carmencita             | 0    |
|  2 | Le clown et ses chiens | 0    |
|  3 | Pauvre Pierrot         | 0    |
+----+------------------------+------+
```

How can i copy the year column from table 1 to table two so that they have correct ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will update the *year* column in Table2 to match the value in Table1 where the *id* is the same in both tables:

```
update Table2
inner join Table1 on Table1.`id` = Table2.`id`
set Table2.`year` = table1.`year`;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e53d/1)

For reference: [MySQL manual for UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)